# Нужна ли запятая перед сочетанием "не ниже чем в двойном размере"?

Tags: пунктуация

Такая сверхурочная работа оплачивается не ниже чем в двойном размере.

Comment: Спасибо за принятие ответа. А почему не голосуете треугольнигами, расположенными справа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая не нужна:

***Такая сверхурочная работа оплачивается (как?) не ниже чем в двойном размере***.

Обстоятельственный оборот не требует обособления запятой, относится к глаголу-сказуемому, с которым он тесно связан по смыслу (но не является его частью!).

Comment: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_68

Comment: @Sharon Я позже отвечу вам, сейчас времени нет.